# How to Delete all deleted files with git rm all_files

Tags: git

I just deleted all unnecessary files by deleting them in the directory.

How do I delete all deleted files with git without individually git rm-ing  each of the file names?

Comment: Just for future readers: You should've just used `git rm` on these files instead deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are now changed files, `git commit -a` will commit all these deletions at once.

For the future: use `git rm` instead of just deleting your files. It not only removes files from the index, but also deletes them from disk.

Comment: After doing this,  I don't get anything ?

Answer (score 1):

`git rm <path>` is in effect the same as doing `rm <path> && git add <path>`. You already did the first part of this (`rm <path>`), so what's left is `git add <path>`.

To add all changes (a deletion counts as a change) while avoiding any files not yet tracked, use `git add -u`.

More info at [man git-rm](https://gitirc.eu/git-rm.html), [man git-add](https://gitirc.eu/git-add.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can also just do "git add ." then all deleted files within the directory get status updated and you can commit it